# Show hide one DIV at a time onClick

Tags: javascript, jquery, slick.js

Hi I have three images that load when the page loads, when I click on an image, a carousel appears in it's place. But at the moment all images display the carousel.

What I actually want is, when you click on a specific image, the carousel must appear for that image only (the carousel replaces that image), then when you click on another image (not in the carousel) then the current carousel must disappear and the next carousel appears over the other image that the user has clicked. If the users clicks the carousel that has appeared it goes back to the image that was there initially. So in effect one carousel must be displayed at a time when the user clicks on one of the images.

Here is the code: I can't seem to get it working in here but it is working in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/protonus/pxf39fef/2/) (what am I doing wrong in here?)

```js
$(function() {
  $("#div2, #div4, #div6").hide();
  $("#div1, #div2, #div3, #div4, #div5, #div6").on("click", function() {
    $("#div1, #div2, #div3, #div4, #div5, #div6").toggle();
  });
});
$('.carousel-one').slick({
  arrows: true,
  infinite: true,
  speed: 500,
  slidesToShow: 1,
  centerMode: true,
  variableWidth: true,
  autoplay: true,
  autoplaySpeed: 2000
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.3.15/slick.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.3.15/slick.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
<div id="div1"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/600/200" alt="Image three"></div>
<div id="div2">
  <div class="carousel-one">
    <div><img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200" alt="Image three"></div>
    <div><img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200" alt="Image one"></div>
    <div><img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/200" alt="Image two"></div>
    <div><img src="http://lorempixel.com/320/200" alt="Image four"></div>
    <div><img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200" alt="Image five"></div>
    <div><img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200" alt="Image seven"></div>
    <div><img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/200" alt="Image six"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="div3"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/600/200" alt="Image three"></div>
<div id="div4">
  <div class="carousel-one">
    <div><img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200" alt="Image three"></div>
    <div><img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200" alt="Image one"></div>
    <div><img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/200" alt="Image two"></div>
    <div><img src="http://lorempixel.com/320/200" alt="Image four"></div>
    <div><img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200" alt="Image five"></div>
    <div><img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200" alt="Image seven"></div>
    <div><img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/200" alt="Image six"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="div5"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/600/200" alt="Image three"></div>
<div id="div6">
  <div class="carousel-one">
    <div><img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200" alt="Image three"></div>
    <div><img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200" alt="Image one"></div>
    <div><img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/200" alt="Image two"></div>
    <div><img src="http://lorempixel.com/320/200" alt="Image four"></div>
    <div><img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200" alt="Image five"></div>
    <div><img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200" alt="Image seven"></div>
    <div><img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/200" alt="Image six"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

So basically one carousel should be active at any give time when the user clicks on one of the images.

Comment: I'd avoid targeting classes in javascript and target only id's or data attributes unless you really really have too.

Comment: Ok now I am confused? Is it better to use ID's or Classes? Does it matter? I know ID's are one per page and Classes are multiple per page.

Comment: @Dino, for what you have you should use classes otherwise your selector is gets as long as your edit and won't work anymore for what you want

Comment: Telling someone to target classes is bad advice, target data-attributes in this case, which can and should happily be applied to multiple elements. It's rudimentary clean code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are plenty of different ways to tackle this and this solution is certainly not bulletproof. This should help you grasp the concept though:

Targeting classes with javascript is not bad but you do need to grasp the concept of:

```
$(this).hide();
```

Which refers to the current element that has been clicked.

http://jsfiddle.net/5rtce4ov/

Comment: Hi @Stephan-v With your code, how would I only allow one element to be "active" at one time. So when the page loads there are those three images that are loaded by default. When you click on any one of them, the carousel appears, when you click on another image, the carousel that was active disappears and then the new one appears. So in effect only one carousel is active at any one time.

Comment: Isn't that exactly what I currently happening in my jsfiddle? When you click an image the carousel will appear, try clicking another and you will see the other one close.

Comment: Oh it IS working. Sorry don't know why I did not realise it earlier or see it earlier.

Comment: if I click on the same carousel how can I revert it back to previous image, it is working as stated, but if they click the same carousel, how would I make the carousel disappear and the image come back, so in effect all three images are back on the screen. Hope you understand.

Comment: @Pete but in your solution the other carousel's don't revert to the previous image. Stephan's solution is almost there, except that when I click the active carousel it doesn't revert back to the image.

Comment: @Dino Beware, this is not a proper solution by any means but I will leave it to you to clean this add. To add proper classes, optimize the jQuery and add wrappers. http://jsfiddle.net/5rtce4ov/1/